# ArrayList IndexOutOfBoundsException at position 0

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a strange problem in an android app. 
I have an ArrayList and i try to get the first item with get(0).
But the App sometimes crashs because of an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

The code:

```
int currentItemPosition = 0;
if(!mArrayList.isEmpty()) {
   currentItem = mArrayList.get(currentItemPosition);
}
```

How is that possible?

The Log:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
...
```

Comment: Is `mArrayList` accessed/updated by multiple threads?

Comment: youe mArrayList is empty and u r geting value from list

Comment: Is that the actual code you are running or a demo?

Comment: Demo code but it's the same. I just tried a simple Java program: 
 http://pastebin.com/U9nyEGYj

So how is that possible when o ask for isEmpty. 
And the ArrayList is modified only of a single thread

Comment: @Fabian Is it modified by the same thread that contains the code you posted?

Comment: Nope the ArrayList is modified only of a single thread.

Comment: How did you create your ArrayList?

Comment: `Invalid index 0, size is 0` The array has no elements. So the first element (with index 0) does not exist.

Comment: Yep. But i check the arrayList if it's empty before accessing the first element.

Comment: @Fabian Are you sure this is this line which throws the exception? Is it a List used by an adapter? Could you reproduce a little program that demonstate this behaviour?

Comment: @Fabian can you print your array list and post output

Comment: is `mArrayList` null??

Comment: @Prag'sシ if the list was null it would throw a NPE when calling isEmpty()

Comment: The only possible option is that the list is being modified between the empty() check and the ArrayList.get(). You should look for other threads modifying the list. As you are running the code in Android app, maybe something is modifying your list. More code about the List creation and when the exception is being thrown could help

Comment: `isEmpty()` won't return true, if `mArrayList` is **null** (never instanced).

Comment: This is the complete method which is called:
http://pastebin.com/2fYnbG9b
I get the arraylist from a Viewpager - but nothing is null! No NullPointerException. 
The Problem is, that i can't reproduce this crash -  but the crash logs in developer console are telling me that in this line a IndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown.

Comment: Try this:

int currentItemPosition = 0;
synchronized(mArrayList){
if(!mArrayList.isEmpty()) {
   currentItem = mArrayList.get(currentItemPosition);
}
}

Comment: I will try this and release a new version in play store. Because the only really reason for the IOOBException is that the ArrayList is updated by another thread. 
But there is no other Thread or Task in this class and the ArrayList is a private member without get or set.
Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

As described (single `ArrayList`, single thread, &c), the problem seems kind of "impossible". However, if this (http://pastebin.com/2fYnbG9b) is your actual snippet:

```
private void showFirstItemOfPage() {
    mCurrentBlockItem = 0;
    if(mBlocksList.get(mPager.getCurrentItem()) != null && !mBlocksList.get(mPager.getCurrentItem()).isEmpty())
    {
        addSingleItem(mBlocksList.get(mPager.getCurrentItem()).get(mCurrentBlockItem));
    }      
}
```

perhaps the answer is that `mBlocksList` is actually empty? You're not checking `isEmpty()` for **that** list, only for the lists it contains.

Comment: As i told in comments. "The Problem is, that i can't reproduce this crash - but the crash logs in developer console are telling me that in this line a IndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown"
I nullcheck the mBlocklist item - if the mBlocklist would throw the OOBException. 
But the crash log refers to the addSingleItem line.